# react-native -- log-in button checks auth, sets state, and navigates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

Relatively new to react-native and firebase. Attempting to create a simple form that would allow an admin to enter their e-mail and password, click a log-in button, and get redirected to a separate component via Navigator. Here's the code I've written so far:

```
class AdminLogIn extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loggedIn: false,
      email: '',
      password: '',
      currentError: null
    }
  }

  navigate(routeName){
    this.props.navigator.push({
      name: routeName,
    })
  }

  authCheck() {
    let currentError = this.state.currentError;
    let _this = this;
    let email = this.state.email;
    let password = this.state.password;
    let loggedIn = this.state.loggedIn;

    RNRSAuth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
      let errorCode = error.code;
      let errorMessage = error.message;
      if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
        _this.setState({currentError: errorCode});
      } else {
        _this.setState({currentError: errorMessage});
      };
    });
    console.log(currentError);
    console.log(loggedIn);
    console.log(email);

  }

  loginButtonClick(authCheck){
    let currentError = this.state.currentError;
    this.authCheck();
    if (currentError === null) {
      this.navigate('adminmenu');
      console.log(currentError);
    } else {
      console.log(currentError);
    };
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.adminLogIn}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.adminLogInField}
        onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email})}
        value={this.state.email}
        keyboardType="email-address"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.adminLogInField}
        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
        defaultValue="Password"
        value={this.state.password}
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
      <Button
        style={styles.adminLogInButton}
        title="Log In"
        onPress={this.loginButtonClick.bind(this) }
       />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default AdminLogIn;
```

My initial instinct was to use a third conditional on the signInWithEmailAndPassword promise that set the loggedIn state to true if it didn't return any errors, but I don't believe it enters the .catch if there's no error. Alternately, I was thinking of doing away with the loggedIn state and somehow use the Navigator to return the AdminMenu component if currentError === null. The way it's currently set up, the click returns null for currentError regardless of what I put for email/password and it navigates to the 'adminmenu' every time.

Could really use some guidance as to how to call this.loginButtonClick.bind(this), possibly set the state, then check that state and render the next component or spit the currentError. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Wound up doing away with the loggedIn/currentError approach outlined above and settled on this, with the loading state initially set to false:

```
  login() {
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
    RNRSAuth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password
    ).then((userData) =>
      {
        this.setState({ loading: false });
        this.navigate('adminmenu');
      }
    ).catch((error) =>
        {
          this.setState({ loading: false });
          alert('Login Failed. Please try again'+error);
        }
    );
  }
```

It checks the auth and navigates if the user exists or spits back an error alert if they do not.